# MySQL get all rows in which one field belongs to array, and all members have a common value in the other field

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table of user properties:

```
id, user_id  properties
1,  NULL,    prop_ss1
2,  NULL,    prop_ss2
3,  2,       prop_1
4,  2,       prop_2
5,  3,       prop_1
6,  3,       prop_2
7,  3,       prop_3
8,  4,       prop_1
```

Given an array of user_ids, how could I get the list of all properties which either have the user_id NULL (call it a global property if you wish), or are shared among all user_ids in the given array?

For instance, given an array (2,3), I would like to get:

```
prop_ss1
prop_ss2
prop_1
prop_2
```

Or, given an array(2,3,4), I would like to get:

```
prop_ss1
prop_ss2
prop_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a UNION of two separate queries:

```
SELECT properties FROM your_table WHERE user_id IS NULL

UNION

SELECT properties
FROM your_table
WHERE user_id IN (2, 3)
GROUP BY properties
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd707/4)

The number `2` in the last line is the number of users that you are querying for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct properties from table
where user_id is null
or user_id in (1,2,3)
```

Sorry misread your post, need group by and having